# global function to apply filter to custom field

Tags: custom-field, filters

I have an action hook which works perfectly for the_content.
I would like to apply the same hook anytime a handful of custom_fields are requested.

The custom fields are 1) myfieldone 2) myfieldart 3) myfieldestion
So lets just take one of those - "myfieldone"
Is there a way - where anytime "myfieldone" custom field is requested, that I could filter the value (the_content) of THAT custom field?

I would assume it would be as simple as

```
add_filter('myfieldone', 'my_add_a_class_function', 10,8);
//or 
add_action('myfieldone', 'my_add_a_class_function');
```

However neither of those have any effect.

I've also tried to globally apply it to all get_meta, get_meta_key

```
add_filter('get_meta', 'my_add_a_class_function', 10,8);
add_filter('get_meta_key', 'my_add_a_class_function', 10,8);
//no such luck. What am I missing?
```

So I basically want to do

```
$which_meta_key = 'myfieldone';
add_action($which_meta_key, 'my_add_a_class_function');
```

Here's how I'm doing it with the_content.

```
add_action('the_content', 'my_add_a_class_function');
function my_add_a_class_function($content){

    $sample_html = $content;    

// grab all the matches for img tags and exit if there aren't any
if(!preg_match_all('/<img.*\/>/i', $sample_html, $matches))
  exit("Found no img tags that need fixing\n");

// check out all the image tags we found (stored in index 0)
//print_r($matches);

// iterate through the results and run replaces where needed
foreach($matches[0] as $string){
    // keep this for later so that we can replace the original with the fixed one
    $original_string = $string;

    // preg_replace only replaces stuff when it matches a pattern so it's safe to
    // just run even if it wont do anything.

    $classes = 'TEST'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'
    // check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor
    if ( preg_match('/<img.*? class=".*?">/', $string) ) {
      $string = preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $string);
    } else {
      $string = preg_replace('/(<img.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" >', $string);
    }

    // now replace the original occurence in the html with the fix
    $sample_html = str_replace($original_string, $string, $sample_html);  

} 

return $sample_html;    
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The below custom meta key call appears to work well.
However - I am getting the "found no img tags that need fixing" {if /EXIT} message

```
... // pass the custom_meta content to my filter. 
$sample_content = $content
print_r($sample_content);

//YIELDS
    <p><img class="alignleft" width="175" height="175" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/brother-in-law.gif" alt="">
Peter, My brother-in-law informed me that he has a new job at IBM.</p>
```

However before I apply the filter - I check to see that there are images to filter. and exist if not.
Apparently, no images are being found - although by the print_r - - an image tag clearly exists.

```
if(!preg_match_all('/<img.*\/>/i', $sample_html, $matches))
  exit("Found no img tags that need fixing\n");

// YIELDS:
Found no img tags that need fixing

//however it does echo out my custom field html code, the image and paragraph text display - - because thats part of the get_meta_data - where I initially request the custom field.
```

**SO - QUESTION** - is this a simple regex issue? Do I have mal-formed regex for my

```
preg_match_all ('/<img.*\/>/i'...
```

**OR** - do I need to apply a "to_string" filter to the content so it finds an image as an image rather than just text

Comment: That code doesn't really seem to match up with the (minimal) description of the problem. I see nothing in that code that has to do with meta fields. What am I missing?

Comment: Thats what I'm asking. How would I apply the same filter to meta key value? Where $content passed in was the value of the meta key.  
    add_filter('the_meta_key', 'multiedit_Story1', 10,8);
multiedit_Story1 is the name of the custom field
This comes from a plugin called "pagely-multiedit"
So I was wondering if there was a way in functions.php that I could apply a filter to that custom field everytime its requested.

Comment: My goal is to apply this outside the loop. Can you do a filter without having a specific custom field name/key?
Something like if( is_page_template('enews_template.php'){    //filter all custom fields generated in this template

Comment: modified original question

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the `get_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter either, hence all I can offer is a further approach to a possible workaround:

*Iff* you don't need to satisfy third parties using `get_post_meta`, but only want to use the filter in your own code, you could write a custom wrapper for `get_post_meta`, which in turn will accept a filter:

```
function wpse94639_get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = '', $single = false ) {
    $metadata = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
    return apply_filters( 'wpse94639', $metadata );
}
```

Now you could use `add_filter( 'wpse94639', 'my_add_a_class_function' );`.

This is only a viable solution, *iff* you don't need to filter results when some other theme/plugin is using the original `get_post_meta`, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I apply the same filter to meta key value?

What you are trying to do-- `add_filter('myfieldone', 'my_add_a_class_function', 10,8);`-- won't work. You can't just make up a hook. They have to be implemented somewhere in the source with [`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) or [`do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action).

The easiest way is to call the function.

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id,'key');
$meta_value = my_add_a_class_function($meta_value);
```

There is not template tag/hook like `the_content` to which you can attach that function, as far as I am aware.

[There is a filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L274) on [`get_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata), which is used by [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) (indirectly), that is constructed like `get_{$meta_type}_metadata`, but honestly I can't get that filter to work in any way that makes sense to me.

> Something like if( is_page_template('enews_template.php'){ //filter
>   all custom fields generated in this template

Probably not. Custom fields aren't "generated" in a template, and aren't associated with any template in particular but with posts/pages/CPTs. If you managed to make that work it would be complicated and convoluted-- unless someone can get that `get_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter working, at which I have sadly failed.

Comment: thank you s_ha_dum I had seen another posting somewhere that mentioned using that and could not get it to work either.

The other above suggestion looks like it will be a nice workaround. 
Simple enough - but I;m sure you know how it is. You stare at something so long you forget the simplest things.

will post with results soon.